# Use class method to sorting numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to class method in python

I have a questions about create a sorting function by myself, the requirement is I have to create two class functions. one is called MarblesBoard and another one is Solver. 
The output should be like below:

```
>>> board2 = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2))
>>> solver = Solver(board2)
>>> solver.solve()
1 3 0 2 
3 0 2 1 
0 2 1 3 
2 1 3 0 
1 2 3 0 
2 3 0 1 
3 0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
total steps: 7
```

I am able to create the MarblesBoard Class, and  the Solver Class, but now I got infinite loop when I run the Slover Class.

```
class MarblesBoard:

    def __init__(self, balls):
        self.balls = balls    

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(str(i) for i in self.balls)

    def switch(self):
        lst=list(self.balls)
        lst[0], lst[1] = lst[1], lst[0]  
        self.balls = tuple(lst)
        print(self.balls)

    def rotate(self): 
        lst=list(self.balls)
        lst = lst[1:]+lst[:1]
        self.balls=tuple(lst)
        print(self.balls)

    def is_sorted(self):
        sorted=True
        lst=list(self.balls)
        for i in range(0,len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i]>lst[i+1]:
                sorted=False
                break
        return sorted

class Solver:

    def __init__(self,values):
        self.values=values

    def solve(self):
        steps=0
        while self.values.is_sorted() == False:
            self.values.switch()
            print(values)
            steps=steps+1
            self.values.rotate()
            print(values)
            steps=steps+1
            print(f"total steps is {steps}")
```

Comment: Hi! And welcome to SO. Could you make sure your code is runnable, e.g., line 18 has `lst=` which is a breaking error. Also, please fix indentations.

Comment: Hi Andre, I am not sure why the lst part is missing.  I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MarblesBoard:
    def __init__(self, balls):
        self.balls = self.lst = list(balls)
    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(str(i) for i in self.lst)
    def switch(self):
        self.lst[0], self.lst[1] = self.lst[1], self.lst[0]  
        #print(self.balls)
    def rotate(self): 
        self.lst = self.lst[1:]+self.lst[:1]
        #print(self.balls)
    def is_sorted(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.lst)-1):
            if self.lst[i]>self.lst[i+1]:
                return False
        return True
class Solver:
    def __init__(self,mb):
        self.mb=mb
    def solve(self):
        steps=0
        while True:
            self.mb.switch()
            steps=steps+1
            print(self.mb)
            if self.mb.is_sorted():
                print("Sorted with %d steps" %(steps))
                break

            self.mb.rotate()
            steps=steps+1
            print(self.mb)
            if self.mb.is_sorted():
                print("Sorted with %d steps" %(steps))
                break

mb = MarblesBoard((1,3,0,2))
solver = Solver(mb)
```

Notice:

- Don't change between types too often (just use a list)
- the new `is_sorted()` function
- I test after every step if the marble boad is solved

EDIT:
After calling `self.mb.is_sorted()`, the `MarblesBoard` instance checks, if it is sorted. If one number is not higher than the previous one, the function stops and returns `False`. If this case doesn't occur, the function will return `True` by default. 
Now in `solve` I check after *every* operation to the board, if it is sorted. If so, then the otherwise infinite `while` loop will be stopped via `break`.

Comment: "try this" - you should explain what is different and why it solves the problem, to make this answer more useful.

Comment: Hi Brain, this is works, but can you explain more about the logic from if self.mb.is_sorted(): to the end, I am not sure the two'break' command mean

Comment: I hope it is clearer now, I gave the answer too little time, sorry

Comment: Hi Brain, it is clearer now.  My questions does the while loop use both switch and rotate function? Based on my poor understanding, I thought if the first break happened, then the self.mb.rotate() will never be used.

Comment: Excactly; it will never be used, because the Board is already sorted